# React JS - How to always show Address Bar on page load (Mobile)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, mobile

So, I'm having some issues when loading a new page on mobile. Whenever I use a Link to another page AND my address bar is hidden because I did some scrolling, it is leaving the address bar space on the bottom of the page. Im testing on my android phone.

So I'm trying to figure out a way to always show the address bar on Page load to fix this issue. I've checked a lot of sites on mobile and pretty much everyone does this, but I've searched a lot and couldn't find anything that worked. Any ideas how to solve this or point me in the right direction is greatly appreacited. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a single page application? Have you tried resetting the scroll position to zero when the page changes?

Comment: It is a single page application. Yes, I've tried with `window.scrollTo(0,0)` to no avail..

Comment: I think it's not possible to achieve, since the browser itself is the only responsible to hide the address bar on scrolling. With a single page app you are not giving a "real" url change (get request), so the browser won't show the address bar again until the user interacts with it to do so.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answers. I guess I'll have find a workround this small issue then.